# Filterable en RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, webservice, recyclerview

Estoy intentando hacer un buscador en un RecyclerView, el problema es que ya implemente toda la lógica necesaria que segui de un tutorial, pero a la hora de empezar a escribir en el SearchView no me filtra el contenido, no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, si cuando imprimo el ArrayList donde voy guardando los resultados si me va imprimiendo en consola los datos del Array, el problema es que mis vistas se siguen viendo todos los datos consultados.

Esta es mi fragment donde implemento el SearchView:

```
Convenios extends Fragment implements conveniosAdapter.OnEventMovieListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios> convenios;
    conveniosAdapter conveniosadapter;
    public static final String TAG = com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios.class.getName();

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    public Convenios(){

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.convenios, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        convenios = new ArrayList<>();
        conveniosadapter = new conveniosAdapter(convenios);
        conveniosadapter.setOnEventMovieListener(this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        cargarWebService();

        return view;
    }

    private void cargarWebService() {
        String url = "http://www.webservice.com/weblist.php/lista.php";
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios pacto = null;
        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("convenio");

        try{
            for (int i=0; i<json.length(); i++){
                pacto = new com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios();
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                pacto.setIdConvenio(jsonObject.optInt("idConvenio"));
                pacto.setTituloConvenio(jsonObject.optString("tituloConvenio"));
                pacto.setSubtituloConvenio(jsonObject.optString("subtituloConvenio"));
                pacto.setImagenConvenio(jsonObject.optString("imagenConvenio"));
                pacto.setVigenciaConvenio(jsonObject.optString("vigenciaConvenio"));
                pacto.setDescripcionConvenio(jsonObject.optString("descripcionConvenio"));
                pacto.setUrlConvenios(jsonObject.optString("linkConvenio"));
                convenios.add(pacto);
            }

            conveniosAdapter pactoAdapter = new conveniosAdapter(convenios);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(pactoAdapter);
            conveniosadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }catch (JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No hay ningun convenio para mostrar, intentalo mas tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se pudo consultar la informacion, intentalo nuevamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Error","No se pudo consultar la informacion, intentalo nuevamente");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_busqueda, menu);
        MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        conveniosadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        conveniosadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
}
```

de hecho si imprimo lo que me devuelve a funcion  onQueryTextChange(String s) me imprime lo que estoy escribiendo, y este es mi adaptador donde implemento la busqueda:

```
public class conveniosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<conveniosAdapter.ConveniosViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    List<Convenios> convenios;
    private List<Convenios> filteredList;
    private OnEventMovieListener onEventMovieListener;
    Context context;

    public conveniosAdapter(List<Convenios> convenios){
        this.convenios = convenios;
        this.filteredList = convenios;
    }

    @Override
    public ConveniosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int typeView){

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_convenios, parent, false);
        conveniosAdapter.ConveniosViewHolder conveniosVH = new conveniosAdapter.ConveniosViewHolder(itemView, filteredList);
        context = parent.getContext();
        return conveniosVH;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ConveniosViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Convenios conve = filteredList.get(position);

        holder.tituloConvenio.setText(conve.getTituloConvenio());
        holder.subtituloConvenio.setText(conve.getSubtituloConvenio());
        final String url = new String(conve.getImagenConvenio());
        if(url.isEmpty()){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.nofound).into(holder.imagenConvenio);
        }else {
            Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(holder.imagenConvenio);
        }
        holder.vigenciaConvenio.setText(conve.getVigenciaConvenio());
        holder.urlConvenios.setText(conve.getUrlConvenios());
        holder.descripcionConvenio.setText(conve.getDescripcionConvenio());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.i("TEXTO","Consulta: "+charString);
                    filteredList = convenios;
                } else {

                    List<Convenios> newFilteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Convenios convenios : convenios) {
                        if (convenios.getTituloConvenio().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                            newFilteredList.add(convenios);
                        }
                    }
                    filteredList = newFilteredList;
                    Log.i("FLY","Contenido: "+filteredList);
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                filteredList = (List<Convenios>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public class ConveniosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener{

        TextView tituloConvenio;
        TextView subtituloConvenio;
        ImageView imagenConvenio;
        TextView vigenciaConvenio;
        TextView urlConvenios;
        TextView descripcionConvenio;
        Button showConvenios;
        List<Convenios> convenios;

        public ConveniosViewHolder(View itemView, List<Convenios> convenios){
            super(itemView);
            this.convenios = convenios;
            tituloConvenio = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tituloConvenio);
            subtituloConvenio = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtituloConvenio);
            imagenConvenio = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenConvenio);
            vigenciaConvenio = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vigenciaConvenio);
            urlConvenios = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.urlConvenios);
            descripcionConvenio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripcionConvenio);

            showConvenios = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.showConvenios);
            showConvenios.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.showConvenios:
                    Convenios news = filteredList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DescripcionConvenios.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url",news.getUrlConvenios());
                    intent.putExtra("titulo",news.getTituloConvenio());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        }
    }

    public interface OnEventMovieListener{

    }

    public OnEventMovieListener getOnEventMovieListener() {
        return onEventMovieListener;
    }

    public void setOnEventMovieListener(OnEventMovieListener onEventMovieListener) {
        this.onEventMovieListener = onEventMovieListener;
    }
}
```

Si imprimo lo que me devuelve el For dentro de la funcion de busqueda que es este bloque:

```
for (Convenios convenios : convenios) {
                        if (convenios.getTituloConvenio().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                            newFilteredList.add(convenios);
                        }
                    }
                    filteredList = newFilteredList;
                    Log.i("FLY","Contenido: "+filteredList);
```

Esto es lo que me imprime:

> 2019-09-05 17:54:12.909 23578-23929/? I/FLY: Contenido:
>   [com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@58cec6f,
>   com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@9e4ad7c,
>   com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@d21d605] 2019-09-05
>   17:54:15.684 23578-23932/? I/FLY: Contenido:
>   [com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@58cec6f] 2019-09-05
>   17:54:16.067 23578-23934/? I/FLY: Contenido:
>   [com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@58cec6f] 2019-09-05
>   17:54:16.312 23578-23936/? I/FLY: Contenido:
>   [com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@58cec6f] 2019-09-05
>   17:54:16.512 23578-23938/? I/FLY: Contenido:
>   [com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@58cec6f] 2019-09-05
>   17:54:18.193 23578-23941/? I/FLY: Contenido:
>   [com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@58cec6f] 2019-09-05
>   17:54:18.343 23578-23943/? I/FLY: Contenido:
>   [com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@58cec6f] 2019-09-05
>   17:54:18.579 23578-23945/? I/FLY: Contenido:
>   [com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.model.Convenios@58cec6f]

Que tengo entendido son los resultados que se van filtrando pero en mi vista se ven todos los resultados. no me actualiza o filtra lo que estoy buscando

Comment: Hola que tal, podrias reemplazar el filteredList = newFilteredList por filteredList.clear() y luego filteredList.addAll(newFilteredList) ?

Comment: @Carlosgub ya lo hice pero cuando empiezo a escribir siempre se queda en blanco mi RecyclerView

Comment: @Carlosgub ya lo resolvi, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo que me faltaba hacer era lo siguiente:

En la clase donde implemento el SearchView en el metodo onQueryTextChange(String s) lo que hice fue pasarle el nuevo adaptador que recibia cada vez que escribia en la barra de busqueda y ya se actualizo, quedando de esta forma:

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        conveniosadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(conveniosadapter);
        conveniosadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }

Comment: @Enrique_Espinoza que bueno que te pude "ayudar", seguimos en contacto :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la clase donde se implementa el SearchView en el método onQueryTextChange(String s) lo que me faltaba era pasar el nuevo adaptador con los valores buscados al RecyclerView, quedando de esta forma:

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        conveniosadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(conveniosadapter);
        conveniosadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hola, intenta quitar las lineas recyclerView.setAdapter(conveniosadapter); y conveniosadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); porque no deberias settiar de nuevo el adapter al recycler :D